# mongodump stops without dumping every record

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm am trying to use `mongodump` to dump a collection from Cosmos DB. My command looks like this:

```
mongodump 
    --host some.documents.azure.com  
    --port 10255 
    --out myDump 
    --db someDb 
    --collection someCollection
```

This runs fine and starts dumping out the records. But after a few minutes it stops and says "*done dumping someCollection (2700 documents)*", but there are millions of documents in the collection so I don't understand why it's stopping. I was able to dump out the rest of the collections in the database without any problems so not sure why I'm having trouble with this one.

Does anyone know how I can get a full dump or an alternate method of extracting the data?

Comment: It's likely because Cosmos DB is not MongoDB, but rather an API-level emulation. I would not expect that tools made for actual MongoDB to work well. To dump your Cosmos DB data, you might want to check out Cosmos DB tools provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, CosmosDB Mongo API supports a subset of the MongoDB and translates requests into the CosmosDB SQL equivalent. CosmosDB Mongo API has some different behaviours and results. But the onus is on CosmosDB to improve their emulation of MongoDB.(You could see many such different features in so forum)

So, maybe you can't treat with cosmos db mongo api as normal mongo db. Since cosmos db migration tool doesn't currently support Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB either as a source or as a target which is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data), you could refer to the workaround in this [document](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-migrate#use-mongoimport).

Or you could use Azure Data Factory for cosmos db mongo api to export data from cosmos db 
 into [azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) `csv` file,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api).